# How to write a C program which contains swtich case that decides which progam to compile amoung two other c programs

Tags: c, contiki, cooja

i have two c programs

**1.** main_core.c at directory **contiki/mqtt-sn-contiki_examples**

**2.** coap_server.c at directory **contiki/examples/cc26xx/cc26xx-web-demo**

i want to create a third c file at directory **contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router**
this third program should contain a switch case as follows

**case 1:** compile and run **main_core.c**

**case 2:** compile and run **coap_server.c**.

i tried to make header files for both 1 and 2 program then included them in third file but now i don't have any idea what to do ?

how to do this ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just take the argument `1` or `2` as the first command line argument? You know `int main (int argc, char **argv)`? Then just run `./yourprog 1` or `./yourprog 2` and test for the argument with `if (argc != 2 || !isdigit(*argv[1])) { return 1; }` and then `switch (*argv[1] - '0') { ... }`? See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) for why `*argv[1] - '0'`.

Comment: i have to compile these on cooja simulator.Third file need to behave like gateway. How to run ./yourprog1 and ./yourprog2 in switch case?

Comment: Are you stuck on the switch-case, the passing of arguments, or the compilation (and execution) of the C-Files?

Comment: That's just one approach for the C code. I can't help you with cooja simulator? Never heard of it. Someone here will have. You can always use the `system()` command to run the compiler from your `switch()` case.

Comment: To answer this question it may need knowledge of cooja simulator